# C | struct named after a counter

Tags: c, struct

I want to create a struct with a dynamic variable declaration.

E.g. I have a structure called point. I want to create a1, a2, a3, a4, ... which are all of the type point.

The declaration to create this is normally

```
struct point p1;
struct point p2;
```

There is a variable `n` which shall be the number, as a thought it should be

```
struct point (p + valueOf(n))
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

---

The problem is to create, on a call, a struct with the number of a variable included into the name.

`n` is raised by another function and not constant.

Comment: What problem?, it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Use an array: `struct point a[n];`

Comment: You don't want an array of points? The name only has meaning at compile time: unless your counter is determinable at compile time you can't easily generate names, but then you'd also need a way of using them dynamically too.

Comment: What does question *title* means ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Since C99 C has variable-length arrays so you probably don't need dynamic memory allocation.

What you can do is:

```
int i;
for(i = 5; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    struct point p[i];
    /* Do something with p */
}
```

Arrays have elements indexed from `0` to `size-1` so in this case the first element is `p[0]` and the last is `p[i-1]`.

---

If `n` is not constant at compile-time, you need to use dynamic memory allocation. As Gopi answered, this:

```
struct point *p = malloc(sizeof(struct point) * n);
```

Will do the trick. However, when you dynamically allocate memory, you have to remember to free it after you stop using it.

```
free(p);
```

If you don't, then you may leak memory, i.e. you will have some allocated memory but you won't have access to it. For example:

```
void foo(int i)
{
    struct point *p = malloc(sizeof(strutc point) * i);

    /* Do something with p */

    free(p);
}
```

Each time you call `foo()` a new array will be allocated. If you don't have that `free(p);` at the end of the function, you will leak memory because the allocated array will be inaccessible but will still take up that memory. With enough calls to `foo()` without freeing the memory your program will crash because there won't be anymore memory for it to allocate.

Comment: Happy to help! As others pointed out, you have to be careful with dynamic memory allocation. If you don't need it, use arrays.

Comment: C has variable length arrays, so you don't necessarily need to use `malloc`. In fact, it may be better not to.

Comment: True, I forgot about that because at my university we didn't use C99... I'll edit my answer a little to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct point *p = malloc(sizeof(strutc point) * n);
```

Use `malloc()` to allocate memory dynamically so you can specify size as shown above. Once the allocated memory is used you need to free it using `free(p)`

Comment: I still have the hope that you will stop using `malloc` for everything. Specially for people trying to learn c, `malloc` is a dangerous tool for them.

Comment: @iharob Sorry what is wrong with it? It serves the purpose.

Comment: free them with `free(p);`

Comment: @Emadpres Meant to be generic anyways !!

Comment: @Gopi sombody who doesn't know how to allocate memory, he doesn't know how to use `free` also.

Comment: @Emadpres If we just mention what needs to be done instead of giving out the actual answer OP might end up learning more about `free()` i though :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, suppose `N` is a constant, then

```
struct point p[N];
```

And then *p<sub>n</sub>* would be

```
p[n - 1]
```

and then you can access each element from `0` to `N - 1`.

And this is called and **Array**.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for an array:

```
struct point a[n];
```

Then access the elements as `a[0]`, `a[1]`, .... `a[n-1]`.

If `n` is too large, you may need to allocate dynamically with `malloc` The down-side is that you must remember to de-allocate with `free`.